# Applications of Hilbert's metric

Tags: big-list, convex-geometry, applications

Among the fascinating constructions in mathematics is the [Hilbert metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_metric) on a bounded convex subset of ${\mathbb R}^n$.

> Where, within mathematics, is it used ? I know at least a proof of the Perron--Frobenius Theorem for non-negative matrices.
>
> What are its applications in other sciences ?

Comment: Excellent question Denis! I'd wanted to ask a question along these lines for quite some time now.

Comment: How about a link or definition of the Hilbert distance?

Comment: Dear Denis, I would like to ask you, if you don't mind, to explain a bit more why you find this construction fascinating. Also, could you explain a bit how one can prove Perron-Frobenius theorem using Hilbert metric? Would this be some proof that is more conceptual, than a usual one?


Answer (score 7):

Garrett Birkhoff used the Hilbert metric (he called it the projective metric) to prove that every $n$-by-$n$ matrix $A$ with positive entries is a Hilbert metric contraction on the cone of nonnegative vectors.  He gave a formula for the contraction constant which is $\frac{1}{4} \arctan \Delta $ where $\Delta$ is the maximum Hilbert's (projective) metric distance between $Ae_i$ and $Ae_j$ where $e_i$ and $e_j$ are distinct elementary basis vectors.  This immediately implies one aspect of the Perron-Frobenius theorem: that matrices with positive entries have a unique Perron eigenvector.

G. Birkhoff, **Extensions of Jentzsch’s theorem.** Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 85
(1957), 219–227.

The Hilbert metric proof of the Perron-Frobenius theorem also extends to nonlinear maps which are monotone and homogeneous of degree one (i.e., $f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$, $\forall \lambda > 0$).  This is the primary advantage of using the Hilbert metric to prove the Perron-Frobenius theorem.

Comment: This is precisely what I mentionned in my question.

Answer (score 6):

This might not be considered an application, but Hilbert metrics have been studied geometrically and dynamically. Here are several examples of questions that have been partially or totally answered:

- when is a convex domain endowed with its Hilbert metric $\delta$-hyperbolic?
- what is the volume entropy of Hilbert metrics?
- does there exist convex sets that admit a cocompact group of isometries (relative to their Hilbert metric)? (the answer is yes!)

I guess that amoung these, the last part can be considered an application: Hilbert metrics yields interesting subgroups of $\mathrm{PSL}(n,\mathbb{R})$.

For more details you can look at the works of [Yves Benoist](http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~benoist/prepubli/prepublication.html) (in particular the "convexes divisibles" series and "Convexes hyperboliques et fonctions quasisymétriques", in french), [Constantin Vernicos](http://constantin.vernicos.org/Enfrancais/costiapub.html), [Ludovic marquis](http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/ludovic.marquis/Recherche.html) and [Mickaël Crampon](http://mikl.crampon.free.fr/recherche.html).

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

I found the following nice survey paper that lists lots of applications of Hilbert's metric (Birkhoff's version):

[Birkhoff's version of Hilbert's metric and its applications in analysis](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.7921) by *Bas Lemmens, Roger Nussbaum*, April, 2013.

---

Not Hilbert's metric directly, but immediately related is the *Thompson metric* which is frequently used.

I list below two interesting examples.

1. Solving nonlinear matrix equations:

   [Invariant metrics, contractions and nonlinear matrix equations](http://iopscience.iop.org/0951-7715/21/4/011)  by *H. Lee* and *Y. Lim*
2. Dynamic Programming:

   [Thompson metric, contraction property and differentiability of policy functions](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167268197000693) by *L. Montrucchio*

Answer (score 2):

See e.g. pages 167-169 of "Topics in nonlinear analysis & applications" By Donald H. Hyers, George Isac, Themistocles M. Rassias. You can read it on Google books.